# function call by function call with object in c++

Tags: c++, function, object, methods

I want to call the function `show()` by calling the function `folder()` with the help of an object.
`obj.folder() -> show();`
Here, the function `show()` is not doing its job.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int count=0;

class file{
    int roll;
    public:
        void folder()
        {
            ++count;
            roll=count;
            void show();
        }
        void show(){cout<<roll<<endl;}
};
int main()
{
    file obj;
    obj.folder();
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the `void` keyword when calling `show()` inside `folder()`

Comment: Also remove `using namespace std;` as `std::count` also exists and causes warnings - live - https://godbolt.org/z/ac11WMK5o

Comment: Calling syntax a function is explained in any [beginner c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: `void show();` is a function declaration. `show();` is a function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My dude, you did not call `show` inside `folder`, u just declared a global function `void show()` instead.

Comment: It's hard to see what this adds to the other answer, which was posted some 10 minutes earlier.

Answer (score 4):

The **problem** is that your function *calling syntax* (`void show();`) is incorrect. By writing `void show();` you're actually declaring a global free function named `show` that has no parameters and has a return type of `void`.

The correct way to *call* the function would be to remove the `void`, as shown below:

```
void folder()
{
//-v---------->removed void from here   
   show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much, what a silly mistake that destroyed my 3 hours..

Comment: @GhimireSuraj It happens. You're welcome.